# Active Directory integration with Jira, Stash and Bamboo

Tags: active-directory, integration, jira, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I wanna use Microsoft AD for my users to authenticate in the Atlassian products.

What is the best way?

Option 1:

```
Jira -> AD
Stash -> AD
Bamboo -> AD
```

Can I centralize the access to AD?

Something like this below, is it possible?

Option 2:

```
Jira -> AD 
Stash -> Jira
Bamboo -> Jira
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should have a look at the Atlassian user identity tool called Crowd (http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview)

It will help you centralize all the access rights for the atlassian tools.